# Right use of Abbreviations

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I have defind a new glossary entry:

```
\newglossaryentry{gls:USB} {
  name={Universal Serial Bus},
  description={USB, short for Universal Serial Bus, is an industry standard developed in the mid-1990s that defines the cables, connectors and communications protocols used in a bus for connection, communication, and power supply between computers and electronic devices},
}
\newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls:USB}}]{USB}{USB}{Universal Serial Bus\glsadd{gls:USB}}
```

*I got that from here: [Separate Glossary and List of Acronyms](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Separate_Glossary_and_List_of_Acronyms)*

If I now use:

```
In general, there are three basic kinds or sizes related to the \gls{gls:USB} connectors and types of established connection.
```

I get:

> In general, there are three basic kinds or sizes related to the
>   **Universal Serial Bus** connectors and types of established connection.

So I get the whole name of the abbreviation.
How can I keep the abbreviation (USB) in the text and just get a link to the glossary entry?

Comment: The first use of a key is expanded to the long description

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE didn't demonstrate how your lists would be repeated, but I would recommend something like the following:

You could use a command like `\knowngls` as defined below to link to your lists without any expansion, or just use `gls` as usual to link to both lists with a conventional expansion upon first use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\knowngls}[1]{\glsdisp{#1}{\glsname{#1}\glsadd{gls:#1}}}



%%% The glossary entry the acronym links to   
\newglossaryentry{gls:usb}{
    name={Universal Serial Bus},
    description={USB, short for Universal Serial Bus, is an industry standard developed in the mid-1990s that defines the cables, connectors and communications protocols used in a bus for connection, communication, and power supply between computers and electronic devices},
}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{usb}{
    type=\acronymtype, 
    name={USB}, 
    description={Universal Serial Bus }, 
    first={Universal Serial Bus (USB) \glsadd{gls:USB}}, 
    see=[Glossary:]{gls:USB}}


\begin{document}
Uncomment one of the two lines below and compile:

%In general, there are three basic kinds or sizes related to the \gls{usb} connectors and types of established connection.

%Or comment out this first line and try out First use  \knowngls{usb}  followed by subsequent uses of the term:  \gls{usb}.  None of these have been expanded.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```